# ESRI JavaScript API - Return coordinates from LocateButton widget?

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have successfully implemented ESRI's JavaScript API's LocateButton widget.  I can zoom to my current location on-click.  However, I've failed finding a method to return the X,Y coordinates of the location  where it zooms.

Any advice or suggested readings?  I'm new to JS but could I use something like an on-click event to return the values?  How would I query them?  Thanks!

I've included the code snippet below:

```
var testSymbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol({
   "angle": 0,
   "xoffset": 0,
   "yoffset": 12,
   "type": "esriPMS",
   "url": "http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Basic/BlackStickpin.png",
   "contentType": "image/png",
   "width": 24,
   "height": 24
});

geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: map,
    highlightLocation: true,
    symbol: testSymbol
}, "LocateButton");
geoLocate.startup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line in the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_locate.html) is this:

> This widget uses the geolocation api to find the users current location.

The geolocation API isn't an ESRI-specific thing, it's Javascript - the LocateButton is just a pretty wrapper around the geolocation library. MDN has some [good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation) on using geolocation, and specifically you're looking for the `getCurrentPosition` function:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved my problem and it is currently implemented correctly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can subscribe to "locate" event of LocateButton widget. Via [help](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/locatebutton-amd.html#locate)